# JavaFX - Make Node invisible for events

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I need to make some Nodes in JavaFX invisible for Mouse Events.
For example, there is a HBox with 6 Elements within and one Rectangle over the HBox, now I need to catch the MouseEntered and MouseExited Events on the 6 Elements of the HBox, which is not possible because the Rectangle is catching them.

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `node.setMouseTransparent(true);` to make the node transparent to mouse event.